# jquery image map - How can I change background sprite image position?

Tags: jquery, imagemap

I am using an image map on a page that i want to tie into an un ordered list and change the position of the sprite background image based on what hot spot they click on ( i hope i explained that properly):

```
<map name="image-map">
<area id="hometownnorth" title="HometownNorth" shape="poly" coords="71,140,71,124" href="#" alt="HometownNorth">
</map>

<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="HomeTownNorth">&nbsp;</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

a.hometownnorth { height:50px; width:325px; background: url(/resources/images/logo.jpg) 0px -6px no-repeat;}
```

So for this example, when the user clicks on the area `#hometownnorth`, it will change the background position to `-324px -6px`

Comment: Uhm, `$('a.hometownnorth').css('background-position', '-324px -6px')` ?

Comment: Consider the uppercase letters, `a.hometownnorth` is not same as `a.HomeTownNorth`...  see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vrf238zr vs this: https://jsfiddle.net/vrf238zr/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attache the click event to the area inside your image-map.
Here is a working example:

(I set the clickable area ONLY to the top-left 50X50 rectangle)

```js
$('#hometownnorth').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#image1').css('backgroundPosition', '-50px -50px');
});
```

```css
img#image1 {
  background: url(http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.png) no-repeat top left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="image1" src="#" width="150" height="150" alt="Planets" usemap="#map1" />

<map name="map1">
  <area id="hometownnorth" title="HometownNorth" shape="rect" coords="0,0,50,50" href="#asd" alt="HometownNorth" />
</map>
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to tweak this and make it work properly. I now have two areas on my map that modify the background of the List Items properly. My question now, is how can i revert one back to its original state, when another is clicked on? 
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#HomeTownNorth').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('li.hometownnorth').css('backgroundPosition', '0px -6px');
     });
     $('#KootenaiCareNetwork').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('li.kootenai').css('backgroundPosition', '0px -97px');
     });
});

Comment: I hate that I cannot format the code properly, my apologies.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle? I will try to have a look

Comment: Ok, i just gave you the full blown page and code... https://jsfiddle.net/yd54vrcs/1/
you can see that I can only cllck on one hot spot at a time, and would like the other hot spots to return to their original state once another is clicked. So basically some sort of .toggle function between all of the functions.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. I think your best solution is not to change the position of the background, but to have an `active` class that once applied to the relevant `li` will change the background-position of that specific element. this way on every click you can remove the `active` class of ALL the `li` elements and add the `active` to the specific element that is related to that click. Let me know if you get the general idea.

Comment: I believe I do... I did find an example on another post. However this example is applying the active element to the LI which is being clicked... how would I apply an active class to an object that I am not actually clicking? 
var selector = '.nav li';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

Comment: You can do `$(selector).on('click', function { $('ul.general li').removeClass('active'); $(li-specific).addClass('active'); } );`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120640/discussion-between-tony-noriega-and-dekel).